# Имеются две таблицы Excel разной размерности. Как в App Designer построить трехмерный график кривой по значениям в зависимости от выбранной таблицы?

Tags: matlab

Есть два файла Excel, каждый с определенными координатами. Нужно построить трехмерный график по координатам в зависимости от выбранного файла (таблица со значениями выбирается с помощью DropDown. Таблицы разной размерности). Пыталась с помощью if-else не получается. Как это можно сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
      % Button pushed function: Plottrajectory
      function PlottrajectoryPushed(app, event)

         if app.DropDown == '1'
           
         app.z1 = table2array(app.k(1,1)); 
         app.z2 = table2array(app.k(2,1));
         app.z3 = table2array(app.k(3,1));
         app.z4 = table2array(app.k(4,1));
         app.z5 = table2array(app.k(5,1));
         app.z6 = table2array(app.k(6,1));
         
         app.y1 = table2array(app.k(1,2)); 
         app.y2 = table2array(app.k(2,2));
         app.y3 = table2array(app.k(3,2));
         app.y4 = table2array(app.k(4,2));
         app.y5 = table2array(app.k(5,2));
         app.y6 = table2array(app.k(6,2));

         app.x1 = table2array(app.k(1,3)); 
         app.x2 = table2array(app.k(2,3));
         app.x3 = table2array(app.k(3,3));
         app.x4 = table2array(app.k(4,3));
         app.x5 = table2array(app.k(5,3));
         app.x6 = table2array(app.k(6,3));

         else 

         app.z1 = table2array(app.k(1,1)); 
         app.z2 = table2array(app.k(2,1));
         app.z3 = table2array(app.k(3,1));
         app.z4 = table2array(app.k(4,1));
         app.z5 = table2array(app.k(5,1));
         app.z6 = table2array(app.k(6,1));
         app.z7 = table2array(app.k(7,1));
         app.z8 = table2array(app.k(8,1));
         app.z9 = table2array(app.k(9,1));
         app.z10 = table2array(app.k(10,1));

         app.y1 = table2array(app.k(1,2)); 
         app.y2 = table2array(app.k(2,2));
         app.y3 = table2array(app.k(3,2));
         app.y4 = table2array(app.k(4,2));
         app.y5 = table2array(app.k(5,2));
         app.y6 = table2array(app.k(6,2));
         app.y7 = table2array(app.k(7,2));
         app.y8 = table2array(app.k(8,2));
         app.y9 = table2array(app.k(9,2));
         app.y10 = table2array(app.k(10,2));

         app.x1 = table2array(app.k(1,3)); 
         app.x2 = table2array(app.k(2,3));
         app.x3 = table2array(app.k(3,3));
         app.x4 = table2array(app.k(4,3));
         app.x5 = table2array(app.k(5,3));
         app.x6 = table2array(app.k(6,3));
         app.x7 = table2array(app.k(7,3));
         app.x8 = table2array(app.k(8,3));
         app.x9 = table2array(app.k(9,3));
         app.x10 = table2array(app.k(10,3));      
         
         end

         if app.DropDown == '1'
       plot3(app.UIAxes, app.x1, app.y1, app.z1, app.x2, app.y2, app.z2,'o');
       hold (app.UIAxes,'on');
       plot3(app.UIAxes, app.x2, app.y2, app.z2, app.x3, app.y3, app.z3,'o');
       plot3(app.UIAxes, app.x3, app.y3, app.z3, app.x4, app.y4, app.z4,'o');
       plot3(app.UIAxes, app.x4, app.y4, app.z4, app.x5, app.y5, app.z5,'o');
       plot3(app.UIAxes, app.x5, app.y5, app.z5, app.x6, app.y6, app.z6,'o');
       
       else 
       plot3(app.UIAxes, app.x1, app.y1, app.z1, app.x2, app.y2, app.z2,'o');
       hold (app.UIAxes,'on');
       plot3(app.UIAxes, app.x2, app.y2, app.z2, app.x3, app.y3, app.z3,'o');
       plot3(app.UIAxes, app.x3, app.y3, app.z3, app.x4, app.y4, app.z4,'o');
       plot3(app.UIAxes, app.x4, app.y4, app.z4, app.x5, app.y5, app.z5,'o');
       plot3(app.UIAxes, app.x5, app.y5, app.z5, app.x6, app.y6, app.z6,'o');
       plot3(app.UIAxes, app.x6, app.y6, app.z6, app.x7, app.y7, app.z7,'o');
       plot3(app.UIAxes, app.x7, app.y7, app.z7, app.x8, app.y8, app.z8,'o');
       plot3(app.UIAxes, app.x8, app.y8, app.z8, app.x9, app.y9, app.z9,'o');
       plot3(app.UIAxes, app.x9, app.y9, app.z9, app.x10, app.y10, app.z10,'o');
       plot3(app.UIAxes, app.x10, app.y10, app.z10, app.x11, app.y11, app.z11,'o');
       end
```

Comment: А чем вас не устраивают стандартные средства Excel для построения графиков?